# What does the second XP marker mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

There's a second number with XP written after it.

[image: 407238xp]

Does anyone know what it means? It's not the XP remaining.

Comment: Could someone explain why people have downvoted and how I can improve the question?

Comment: "It seems so obvious now. – Pureferret 23 mins ago" - probably because they think this isn't worthy of being a question

Comment: @Khaz that's not a reason to downvote though. If everyone down voted a question because they already knew the answer then every question would be down voted.

Comment: That's only me trying to explain why others could have downvoted

Comment: Half of the Pokémon Go questions we have are fairly obvious with minimal investigation. But not everyone sees that initially and they're also informative, so I still upvote them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That number is the total amount of trainer experience you've earned. So, in the image attached in the question, that trainer has earned 72,238 XP at the current trainer level, needs 100,000 XP to reach the next trainer level, and has accumulated 407,238 XP across all levels in total so far.

Comment: It seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

Total experience accumulated throughout all levels.